# jquery - add and remove hightlight

Tags: jquery

I have number of icons. I want to be able to choose number of them by clicking on them. if I click again I would like to remove the checkbox mark and the class that highlight the image.

The code below allow to hightlight the chosen image and add value to the relevant checkbox. how do I remove them when user click on the image again?

```
<span id="tripType">
    <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x tripType" id="1"></i>
    <input type="hidden" name="tripTypes[]" value='' id="tripTypeField1"> 

    <i class="fa fa-system fa-4x tripType" id="2"></i>
    <input type="hidden" name="tripTypes[]" value='' id="tripTypeField2"> 

    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x tripType" id="3"></i>
    <input type="hidden" name="tripTypes[]" value='' id="tripTypeField3"> 
</span>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(".tripType").click (function () {
        var obj = this;
        $(obj).addClass('border-highlight');

        chosenID = $(obj).attr("id");

        $("#tripTypeField" + chosenID).val(chosenID);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I can't see any `checkbox` in your html. The inputs is `type=hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the class first then add it to the selected one.

```
$(".tripType").click (function () {        
    $(".border-highlight").removeClass('border-highlight');
    $(this).addClass('border-highlight');
    chosenID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#tripTypeField" + chosenID).val(chosenID);
});
```